# What is a list of curried programming languages?

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, currying, partial-application

I just learned from another question that Haskell is called a curried programming language because it applies function currying by default. What are other languages that display this behavior?

Comment: What I have done: googled "curried programming languages", checked the first 3 links. googled "curred programming languages list", checked the first 3 links. googled "programming languages by features", checked the first 3 links. Searched on stack overflow for [currying] [programming-languages], [currying] list, [currying].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of the less esoteric languages it is mainly Haskell:

```
f x y z = x + y * z
g = f 4
r = g 7 8
```

OCaml and F#:

```
let f x y z = x + y * z
let g = f 4
let r = g 7 8
```

and to a lesser extent SML (where libraries use currying less):

```
fun f x y z = x + y * z
val g = f 4
val r = g 7 8
```